# What does the descriptor array generated using compute method of class ORB represent?

Tags: python, image, opencv, orb

I am using OpenCV in Python to make a feature descriptor of a give image. For that I am using `ORB` class.What I don't understand is what the descriptor array contains after using `orb.detect` and `orb.compute` methods.

Below is my code.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

img = cv2.imread('penguins.jpg',0)

# Initiate STAR detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=1000)

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img,None)

# compute the descriptors with ORB
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

# draw only keypoints location,not size and orientation
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,des, color=(0,255,0), flags=0, )
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()

print len(kp),len(des),len(des[1]), des[0]
```

The output of the last line is below:

```
1000 1000 32 [221  65  79 237   6   2 111 112 116 194 243  70  83  99 177 113 118 228
  62 238 233 181  37  76 244 171 230 128  45 178  96  49]
```

Why is the length of each element of `des` is 32? What does it represent? I know that it is supposed to be a descriptor array corresponding to each keypoint, but what exactly do those numbers represent?

I have tried the above code from this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html).

Comment: I think you can look at the question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676365/opencv-orb-descriptor-how-exactly-is-it-stored-in-a-set-of-bytes), maybe you can help you

Answer (score 2):

The default **lenght of each ORB descriptor is 32 bytes**. Each byte contains 8 pixel intensity comparisons as explained in the official paper: https://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf

Also check: [OpenCV ORB descriptor - how exactly is it stored in a set of bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676365/opencv-orb-descriptor-how-exactly-is-it-stored-in-a-set-of-bytes)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by 8 pixel intensity comparisons? I am finding the paper hard to read. Thanks.