# How are the binary descriptors generated in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, feature-descriptor, python

I have been working with the binary descriptors that are implemented in OpenCV. But the descriptors are formed with **integer** values (shown in red rectangle).

Why are they formed with integer values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV uses a byte-array to represent a BRIEF descriptor. Thus, every value in the highlighted container is in [0, 255] range, and actually corresponds to 8 bits of the descriptor.
This is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d7d/tutorial_py_brief.html):

> [Descriptor dimension] can be 128, 256 or 512. OpenCV supports all of these, but by
> default, it would be 256 (OpenCV represents it in bytes. So the values
> will be 16, 32 and 64).

Here is a [stellar explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676365/opencv-orb-descriptor-how-exactly-is-it-stored-in-a-set-of-bytes) for why representing the descriptor as a binary array would be less efficient.